# How to get a tensor from an image

Tags: tensorflow.js

I have an image and I would like to get the tensor from it.

Some of the images are already on the frontend server be whereas others will be served by the server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do that, one needs to use [fromPixels](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/0.12.5/#fromPixels)

In case the image is already displayed in an html page
You can consider doing a querySelector to get the image first and then you can use [fromPixels](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/0.12.5/#fromPixels)

**html**

```html
<img id="my-image" src="mydata.jpg">
```

**js**

```js
const image = document.querySelector("#my-image")
const t = tf.fromPixels(image)
```

If the image is not present in the html page, you can use the constructor [Image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image) to create it and then pass it as parameter to [fromPixels](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/0.12.5/#fromPixels)

```
const im = new Image()
im.onload = () => {
  const a = tf.fromPixels(im, 4)
  a.print()
  console.log(a.shape)
}
im.src = "url-of-the-image"
document.body.appendChild(im)
```

[onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/image.onload) makes sure that the image has finished downloading before converting it to a tensor.

If the image url and the url on which the frontend page is served are different there will be a [cross-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) issue when creating the tensor. If the server serves the image with an access control that allows the frontend to retrieve that image, then setting the `crossOrigin` attribute of the image will solve the issue, otherwise there will nothing that can be done to get the tensor from that image.

```js
const im = new Image()
im.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
im.src = "https://i.imgur.com/lVlPvCB.gif"
document.body.appendChild(im)
im.onload = () => {
  const a = tf.fromPixels(im, 4)
  a.print()
  console.log(a.shape)
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Load TensorFlow.js -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tensorflow/0.12.4/tf.js"> </script>
  </head>

  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```