# The image contains cross-origin data

Tags: javascript, tensorflow.js

I'm totally new to JS, but as I have ML background I wanted to explore ML5. I'm trying to do Image classification from https://github.com/CodingTrain/website/tree/master/Courses/beginner_ml5/02_image_classification

I'm getting below error when want to use prediction. I would be grateful for suggestions.

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTZXZ.png)

Comment: Could you copy and paste the error instead of the image? Consider this [post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors) to see why it is not suggested to upload images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you have suggest that you are using an image that is served by a server different from the server that is rendering your frontend page. It is the CORS issue.
To solve it, your server needs to allow your frontend to retrieve images. It means that there should be in the header of the response serving your image the following entry

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*" ( not recommended because allowing everything)
```

or to be more specific

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "url of your frontend" (ex: localhost:4200, website.com)
```

and in your image on the frontend, you need to set the attribute `crossorigin="anonymous"` in your `img` or `canvas` or `video` tag.

If the `allow-origin` fails to be in the server response, there is nothing one can do to process that image, because the error will be thrown no matter what. A similar question was considered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51866875/how-to-get-a-tensor-from-an-image)